# Is Beast Boy's transformation of Justice League vs. Teen Titans a nod to Genomorphs from Young Justice?

Tags: character, reference, young-justice, dc-animated-movie-universe, justice-league-vs-teen-titans

In *Justice League vs. Teen Titans*, during the scenes in the hellish dimension, Beast Boy was able to turn into some new kind of creature like a werwolfish-beast, a griffin and an animal looks just like a Genomorph:

[image][image]

Here is one of the G-Elves (Genomorph) from Young Justice:

[image][image]

They look exactly similar except for the colour which is also Beast Boy's trade of being green in all his transformations. So is it a reference to Young Justice or are both referencing some other comic-book entity? Did they ever acknowledge it?

Comment: Genomorphs come in many different shapes -__- http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/marvel_dc/images/a/a3/Dubbilex_Earth-16_001.png/revision/latest?cb=20111015172515 http://www.writeups.org/wp-content/uploads/Genomorphs-Young-Justice-Animated-Series-c.jpg Not to mention Conner, Arsenal, Match...

Comment: @cde I know, as I have seen the show (and you missed the mind controlling one) but the question is about this specific Genomorph's reference only, not about the type of Genomorphs.